# Screen flickering (only on desktop) with Fedora 20, but why?

Tags: fedora, upgrade, desktop, bugs

I'm using Fedora 20 and since I returned from the weekend, my screen flickers very fast. This occurs only on the desktop (excluding the menubar, with the fedora-menu and the clock, etc.) and the explorer, programs are not affected of this. Selecting anything on the desktop is not possible, probably it's cleaning or refreshing all the time.

I can't think of applying any updates on last use, but today I installed all of the fedora updates and brought the BIOS to the newest version, which didn't solve the problem.

Has anyone an idea where this comes from? (If further information is needed, please let me know.)

### Update

Problem is "solved" if I turn the desktop background in to a straight color instead of a picture, then all misbehavior are disappeared. But this is just a workaround